# Creating a SSH screen through PHP with phpseclib

Tags: php, ssh

I need to start a SSH screen through PHP.  I have a PHP script in which I am trying to create a screen on my ssh server with the PHP SSH library phpseclib. This is the function that I am using to try to create the screen:

```
 function startscreen($ssh, $user)
 {
      $ssh->exec("screen -S ".$user);
 }
```

And this is how I am calling the function:

```
startscreen($ssh, $user);
```

I know I can create screens this way, but it will not work remotely with php. Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can run screen without having a `tty` to which it can bind itself.

Comment: You might find [so] is better for this as they are programming orientated.

Answer (score 1):

Screen needs an actual pty/tty allocated to start in attached mode like you do now. It'll work better if you start it in detached mode (see the manpage, and see stack overflow if you have more programming questions)